# Powerbi world map highlight countries

Tags: powerbi

I have data from excel for a test. like this:

```
Country Sales
NL       5000
BE       10000
DE       500000
US       50
```

so I want to to mark country with highes sale value green and lowest with red.
Right now it shows this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyeVI.png)

is is possible to highlight the whole country so not just a circle but make like a box in the country regions across the country border?

Answer (score 1):

Shape map visual component with custom map specification should give you the desired result:

1) Download [World countries map](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/world-countries.json) JSON file.
2) Drop Shape Map component on the report page. Go to the Format section / Shape / Click "+ Add map" button and select world-countries.json you've downloaded in step #1

3) Trun "Diverging" (if necessary): "Format section / Data colors"
4) Drop Country field in the Location section of the visual and Sales in the Color Saturation section of the visual respectively

The final result should look similar to this one:
[image]